# How do I delete a row from a GridView during the RowDeleting event?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView and its DataSource is `datatable.OnRowDeleting` event of Gridview. I can't seem to delete that row when I click the 'delete' button that invokes the event to remove the row.

My code is like this in `RowDeleting` event of GridView:

```
DataTable.Rows.Remove(GridView.DataKeys(e.rowindex).value)
```

I get the error:

> `"Cannot type cast from System.Int32 To System.Data.DataRow"`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the row to delete inside the `RowDeleting` event by looking at the

```
e.RowIndex
```

You can then use the `e.RowIndex` to find the proper row in your `DataTable`, delete that row, and then refresh you `gridview` by calling .databind() on it once again to that `DataTable`.

**Example:**

```
DataTable1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Delete()
GridView1.DataSource = DataTable1
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Don't worry ramyatk06. Gustavo has given code on your other copy of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665905/deleting-rows-from-datatable-in-vb-net/665931#665931